# Libgdx: при отрисовке sprite элементов массива ошибка Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

Подскажите ответ на такой вопрос:
Упаковал текстуры, подключил атлас и собственно инициализировал изображения, но по нажатию на старт кнопку, вылетает приложение с ошибкой:
сделал даже по старинке:

```
 private void initializeArrayMoney() {
        sprites = new Sprite[15];
        r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
        r2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r2"));
        r5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r5"));
        r10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r10"));
        r20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r20"));
        r50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r50"));
        r100 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r100"));
        r200 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r200"));
        r500 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r500"));
        k1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k1"));
        k2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k2"));
        k5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k5"));
        k10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k10"));
        k20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k20"));
        k50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k50"));
        sprites[0] = r1;
        sprites[1] = r2;
        sprites[2] = r5;
        sprites[3] = r10;
        sprites[4] = r20;
        sprites[5] = r50;
        sprites[6] = r100;
        sprites[7] = r200;
        sprites[8] = r500;
        sprites[9] = k1;
        sprites[10] = k2;
        sprites[11] = k5;
        sprites[12] = k10;
        sprites[13] = k20;
        sprites[14] = k50;
    }
```

вызываю в `onCreate()`.
создаю объекты которым нужно и нарисовать спрайты

```
private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 80;
    raindrop.height = 80;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

Вылетает на этом участке:

```
game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);

        for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++) {
                game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
            }
        }
        game.batch.end();
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

строка: `game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);`

Полный код:

```
    public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements ApplicationListener {

    final Drop game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    Sprite bucketImage, r1, r2, r5,
            r10, r20, r50, r100, r200, r500, k1, k2, k5, k10, k20, k50;

    Sound dropSound;
    Music rainMusic;
    Rectangle bucket;
    Vector3 touchPos;
    Array<Rectangle> raindrops;//Добавляем каплю
    long lastDropTime;
    Sprite[] sprites;
    private static TextureAtlas atlas;

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter;
    Rectangle raindrop;


    public GameScreen(final Drop gam) {
        this.game = gam;
        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/texture.pack"), true);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

        touchPos = new Vector3();

        //dropImage = new SpriteBatch(ResourseLoader.);
        bucketImage = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("bucket"));
        bucketImage.flip(false, true);


        //dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("waterdrop.wav"));
        // rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("undertreeinrain.mp3"));

        // rainMusic.setLooping(true);//музыка
        // rainMusic.play();

        bucket = new Rectangle();
        bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2;
        bucket.y = 20;
        bucket.width = 100;
        bucket.height = 95;
        game.preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("SaveScore");

        raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();

    }

    private void initializeArrayMoney() {

        sprites = new Sprite[15];
        r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
        r2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r2"));
        r5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r5"));
        r10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r10"));
        r20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r20"));
        r50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r50"));
        r100 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r100"));
        r200 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r200"));
        r500 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r500"));
        k1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k1"));
        k2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k2"));
        k5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k5"));
        k10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k10"));
        k20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k20"));
        k50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k50"));
        sprites[0] = r1;
        sprites[1] = r2;
        sprites[2] = r5;
        sprites[3] = r10;
        sprites[4] = r20;
        sprites[5] = r50;
        sprites[6] = r100;
        sprites[7] = r200;
        sprites[8] = r500;
        sprites[9] = k1;
        sprites[10] = k2;
        sprites[11] = k5;
        sprites[12] = k10;
        sprites[13] = k20;
        sprites[14] = k50;



    }

    private void spawnRaindrop() {
        Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
        raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
        raindrop.y = 480;
        raindrop.width = 80;
        raindrop.height = 80;
        raindrops.add(raindrop);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        camera.update();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        //game.font.draw(game.batch, "Drops Collected: " + dropsGatchered, 15, 480);
        game.font.getData().setScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
        game.font.getColor().set(Color.WHITE);

        //game.batch.draw(score, 10, 450);
        game.font.draw(game.batch, " " + game.dropsGatchered, 120, 470);

        game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);

        for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++) {
                game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
            }
        }
        game.batch.end();

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            bucket.x = (int) (touchPos.x - 64 / 2);
        }

        /*if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();*/

        if (bucket.x < 0) bucket.x = 0;
        if (bucket.x > 800 - 64) bucket.x = 800 - 64;

        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRaindrop();

        iter = raindrops.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            raindrop = iter.next();
            nextlevel();
            if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0) {
                iter.remove();

            }
            if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
                game.dropsGatchered++;
                dropSound.play();
                iter.remove();


            }
            if (raindrop.y < 0) {
                game.preferences.putInteger("Cent", game.dropsGatchered);
                game.preferences.flush();
                pause();


            }

        }
    }

    public void nextlevel() {
        raindrop.y -= 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
      /* if (game.dropsGatchered <= 5) {

                raindrop.y -= 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        } else {

           raindrop.y -= (10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) + (game.dropsGatchered);
       }*/


    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        spawnRaindrop();
        initializeArrayMoney();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        rainMusic.stop();
        dropSound.stop();

        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // dropImage.dispose();
        // bucketImage.dispose();
        dropSound.dispose();
        rainMusic.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
//        rainMusic.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: обновил код в шапке темы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что бы я предложил, это вынести параметры, что принимает функция `draw()`, в отдельные переменные и прологировать тело цикла. В итоге получится что-то такое:

```
Log.d("MyActivity", "raindrops = " + raindrops);
for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
    Log.d("MyActivity", "sprites = " + sprites);
    Log.d("MyActivity", "sprites.length = " + sprites.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "i = " + i);
        Sprite sprite = sprites[i];
        Log.d("MyActivity", "sprite = " + sprite);
        int _x = raindrop.x;
        Log.d("MyActivity", "_x = " + _x);
        int _y = raindrop.y;
        Log.d("MyActivity", "_y = " + _y);
        game.batch.draw(sprite, _x, _y);
    }
}
```

Далее прологировать функции инициализации и `render()` и посмотреть не вызывается ли `render()` раньше чем инициализируются массивы.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
Log.d("MyActivity", "render(" + delta + ")");
...
}

private void initializeArrayMoney() {
Log.d("MyActivity", "initializeArrayMoney()");
...
}
```

Это, скорее, не конкретный ответ на вопрос, а последовательность действий как нужно исправлять такого рода ошибки и понять откуда у них ноги растут.
Подозреваю, что первый вызов функции `render()` происходит раньше вызова `create()`, проще всего бороться с этим с помощью флага. Создать переменную класса `private boolean isInitialized = flase;`, в функции `create()` после вызовов всех функций инициализации присваевать ей `true`, в функции `render()` в самом начале сделать проверку по этому флагу и ретурниться, если он не `true`.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
if (!isInitialized) return;
Log.d("MyActivity", "render(" + delta + ")");
...
}
```

Это должно решить проблему.